# Setting an initial "current-offset" and "lag" for new consumer groups for a given topic

Tags: node.js, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I'm working on a product that may add/remove consumer groups depending on how a user uses the product.

`enable.auto.commit` is turned off in our product and instead we commit the offset every time after we receive the data.

We recently implemented a service that will pause/resume the product. The kafka library (in [NodeJS](https://github.com/Blizzard/node-rdkafka)) did not yet have the pause/resume functions available, so I ended up unsubscribing/subscribing to the topic instead based on the consumers consumer group, which seems to work as we intended.

The only problem occurs when a new consumer group is added. First, let me explain the behavior I'm seeing:

Here is consumer "group1" information..

```
$ bin/kafka-consumer-groups.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --describe --group philz-topic-group1

TOPIC                          PARTITION  CURRENT-OFFSET  LOG-END-OFFSET  LAG        CONSUMER-ID                                       HOST                           CLIENT-ID
philz-topic                    1          33              33              0          rdkafka-3ac4d56e-e94b-4365-9af7-04e485502b5d      /10.233.113.109                rdkafka
philz-topic                    4          34              34              0          rdkafka-d642805c-f5ea-4450-9cb0-3272fcbbffc9      /10.233.88.251                 rdkafka
philz-topic                    0          23              23              0          rdkafka-12cfca8b-fd61-4a68-bc5f-1946c8ef4eb1      /10.233.120.55                 rdkafka
philz-topic                    2          26              26              0          rdkafka-7561ca2a-9894-4a3d-83fe-d379bbe64fdf      /10.233.126.40                 rdkafka
philz-topic                    3          20              20              0          rdkafka-cd9d5ed6-7daa-4b75-8f39-6704c8d887ed      /10.233.119.133                rdkafka
```

And here is consumer "group2" information.. Consumer "group2" was just added and completed one operation. So CURRENT-OFFSET and LAG for a single operation has been updated.

```
$ bin/kafka-consumer-groups.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --describe --group philz-topic-group2

TOPIC                          PARTITION  CURRENT-OFFSET  LOG-END-OFFSET  LAG        CONSUMER-ID                                       HOST                           CLIENT-ID
philz-topic                    3          -               20              -          rdkafka-b56306e1-b4b7-43fe-a604-ab7c12f70e9f      /10.233.119.133                rdkafka
philz-topic                    1          -               33              -          rdkafka-76c9a4d2-268b-4ebb-94a8-f1230c9bbfea      /10.233.113.109                rdkafka
philz-topic                    4          34              34              0          rdkafka-d412e574-8241-48c6-af26-c50be44eb51d      /10.233.126.40                 rdkafka
philz-topic                    0          -               23              -          rdkafka-33179a7d-cb9f-453a-83c6-e7e4780372b6      /10.233.88.251                 rdkafka
philz-topic                    2          -               26              -          rdkafka-77506e87-b666-4c92-82df-82071e2ff801      /10.233.120.55                 rdkafka
```

If a new consumer group was added and no operations were completed, no information about the consumer group is shown with the above command.

The problem I'm facing currently is, when a pause/resume operation occurs and all partitions for a consumer group does not have an updated CURRENT-OFFSET and LAG, when unsubscribing/pausing and completing an operation, a partition should have a LAG of 1 now. But if a new consumer group did not have any previous CURRENT-OFFSET and LAG for the given partition, that information is now skipped and never seen by the consumer group.

My question is, when creating a new consumer group, can we update the CURRENT-OFFSET for the group to match the LOG-END-OFFSET for all available partitions?

I'm not super familiar with Kafka, so any explanation on behavior here is appreciated.

My guess is since we commit offset ourselves (since `enable.auto.commit` is turned off), when an operation occurs, we are able to see some information for the new consumer group, but only see that one partition (the one that just received the data) is shown and updated with current-offset.

Thanks!

Edit:

Also, in my examples, I have 5 consumers per consumer group, and 5 partitions, so one consumer per partition is expected

Comment: Are you setting `auto.offset.reset` as well? If you start a new consumer group, ideally you want to read from the beginning of the topic, not the most recent message.

Comment: I'm not setting `auto.offset.reset`. So do you mean to set it to "earliest"? One concern I have for setting to earliest are situations where a user might remove a consumer group and add the consumer group back. Does "earliest" have each consumer read a partition from the very first offset to its latest offset?

Comment: There's not a very obvious api to remove consumer groups, so I don't think that should be a concern, but yes, that setting should determine to start at the earliest available offset for a new group

Comment: @cricket_007 great! Thank you, just tried it out and seems to set offset for a new groups partitions to the current log-end-offset. Trying it out, seems to solve my problem. If you submit an answer, I will accept it :) I'll need to see implications of setting this config for other use-cases in our product, but for now, lgtm

Comment: Great! I'm not familiar with the Node API, so feel free to post your own answer

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to cricket_007 for providing the kafka consumer option necessary to do this

The consumer option `auto.offset.reset` allows to automatically set a consumers offset on instantiation. By setting the value of this option to 'earliest', it will set current offset of each partition to `LOG-END-OFFSET`.

In order to set this option with the node library, simply:

```
const consumer = new Kafka.KafkaConsumer(config, {
    'auto.offset.reset': 'earliest'
});
```

Where `config` are your key/value pair configurations for the consumer, and the second parameter are your key/value pair configurations to create a default topic configuration.

The config is topic-level config set on the consumer as documented here: https://github.com/edenhill/librdkafka/blob/0.11.1.x/CONFIGURATION.md

Comment: I don't think this is the proper answer to the original question, so removing this as the accepted answer. Reason is that 'earliest' sets the offset to the earliest possible offset, which can lead to re-consuming all entries for a given topic. But I was really looking for a way to just set the offset immediately to the latest on creation and/or subscription of the consumer to a given topic

Comment: The fix applied currently required sending and consuming initial "empty" messages on every available partition when a consumer is first created and using `'auto.offset.reset': 'latest'`. This way we can set the offset before unsubscribing a consumer. I'm viewing this as a temp-fix/workaround, so not posting as an accepted answer